# need to sort the entire array by title Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am using Doctrine 2, here when I am getting array like below.

I have to sort the entire by "title" it has levels for brand name, model name, engine capacity, I need to sort all the title's

```
$repo = $em->getRepository ( 'Teon_Model_Folder' );
$tree = $repo->childrenHierarchy ();
```

I am getting result like this, I need to sort by title in every level

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'id' => int 28
      'title' => string 'BMW' (length=3)
      'slug' => string 'bmw' (length=3)
      'flags' => null
      'lft' => int 2
      'lvl' => int 1
      'rgt' => int 105
      'root' => int 25
      '__children' => 
        array
          0 => 
            array
               'id' => int 128
               'title' => string '3-series' (length=3)
               'flags' => null
               'lvl' => int 2
                ......  
          1 => 
            array
              ...
          2 => 
            array
              ...
          3 => 
            array
              ...
          4 => 
            array
              ...
          5 => 
            array
              ...
  1 => 
    array
      'id' => int 46
      'title' => string 'Ford' (length=4)
      'slug' => string 'ford' (length=4)
      'flags' => null
      'lft' => int 106
      'lvl' => int 1
      'rgt' => int 113
      'root' => int 25
      '__children' => 
        array
          0 => 
            array
              ...
  2 => 
    array
      'id' => int 56
      'title' => string 'Honda' (length=5)
      'slug' => string 'honda' (length=5)
      'flags' => null
      'lft' => int 114
      'lvl' => int 1
      'rgt' => int 123
      'root' => int 25
      '__children' => 
        array
          0 => 
            array
              ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out 
[Sort array by key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)

This should sort array by key - in your case key is title.

Comment: I manage to sort the array in parent level using php, but I don't know how doctrine works